# Proof of $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\right)^n=\sqrt{ab}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ two strictly positive sequences such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^n=a>0\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n^n=b>0.$$

I need to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\right)^n=\sqrt{ab}$$

I have really no idea of what to do and what to look at. Please, could you avoid to give me a complete solution? Could you highlight the things a good mathematician should notice when tackling a problem like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't that the Babylonian algorithm?

Comment: @FalsePromise, placing typographical elements below or above the main line is discouraged in the title, because this often breaks the alignment of the titles on the home page of MSE.

Comment: @E.Joseph, placing typographical elements below or above the main line is discouraged in the title, because this often breaks the alignment of the titles on the home page of MSE. You should have rejected that edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a_n=1+\alpha_n/n$ for some sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ with $\alpha_n \to \log a$.  The same goes for $b_n$ and $\beta_n$.  Ergo

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \Bigl( \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\Bigr)^n =
 \lim_{n\to\infty} \Bigl( 1+ \frac{\alpha_n+\beta_n}{2n} \Bigr)^n =
 \exp\bigl( (\log a + \log b) /2 \bigr) = \sqrt{ab}.
$$

Comment: What can I do to understand why $a_n=1+\alpha_n/n$? I mean can you show me how I can derive it?

Comment: There is always some $\alpha_n$ for which $a_n=1+\alpha_n/n$, correct?  Now, use the fact that $(1+t/n)^n \to e^t$.

Comment: Thank you, now I can understand. What did suggest you that you should express $a_n=1+\alpha_n/n$?

Comment: The fact that you had a limit for $a_n^n$ and I know the limit for $(1+t/n)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

[Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) gives
$$
\begin{align}
1+n(x-1)
&\le(1+(x-1))^n\\[6pt]
&=x^n\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
For $x\ge1$, apply $(1)$ and $1+x\le e^x$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left[\frac{1+x}2\frac{1+1/x}2\right]^n
&=\left[1+\frac{(x-1)^2}{4x}\right]^n\\
&\le\left[1+\frac{x^{2n}}{4n^2x}\right]^n\\
&\le\exp\left(\frac{x^{2n}}{4nx}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Factoring out $a_n^n$ and $b_n^n$ and taking the geometric mean
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_n+b_n}2\right)^n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n^n\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{\frac{a_n}{b_n}+1}2\right]^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^n\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{1+\frac{b_n}{a_n}}2\right]^n\\
&=\sqrt{AB}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{\frac{a_n}{b_n}+1}2\frac{1+\frac{b_n}{a_n}}2\right]^{n/2}\\[12pt]
&=\sqrt{AB}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
by the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) and $(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try another path: naming $A_n = a_n ^n$ we get $A_n\to a$; similarly for $b_n$ and $B_n$.
Now:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\right)^n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{A_n^{1/n}+B_n^{1/n}}{2}\right)^n = \left[1^\infty\right]
$$
therefore we go for the form $(1+1/n)^{n}\to e$:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left[\left( 1+ \frac{A_n^{1/n}+B_n^{1/n} -2}{2} \right)^{{2}/{(A_n^{1/n}+B_n^{1/n} -2)}}\right]^{p_n}
$$
where the expression in the square parenthesis gives $e$ and
$$
p_n = n\frac{A_n^{1/n}+B_n^{1/n} -2}{2} = n\frac{e^{(\ln A_n)/n}+e^{(\ln B_n)/n} -2}{2}
$$
which yields, with Taylor series expansion:
$$
\frac{\ln A_nB_n}{2} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \to \ln \sqrt{ab}.
$$
By collecting the piece we finally have:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\right)^n = e^{\ln{\sqrt{ab}}} = \sqrt{ab}.
$$